# Getting bytearray from PdfDictionary

Tags: itext

Please refer to this picture below taken from itext url https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-5/how-add-alternative-text-image-tagged-pdf. I am trying to get the bytearray of the images in the pdf, while traversing all the branches, looking for structural element marked as /Figure. Goal is to insert a tag (alternate text) to the image as well **get the byte array of that specific image** to which I am adding the alternate text.

[image]

Here is the code

```
 static void manipulate(PdfDictionary element)
    {
        if (element == null)
            return;

        var t = element.GetBytes();
        if (PdfName.FIGURE.Equals(element.Get(PdfName.S)))
        {
            element.Put(PdfName.ALT, new PdfString("Figure without ALT"));

            var byteaarray = element.GetBytes(); //// Here bytearray is null
        }

        var kids = element.GetAsArray(PdfName.K);

        if (kids == null)
            return;

        for(int i = 0; i < kids.Size; i++)
        {
            manipulate(kids.GetAsDict(i));
        }
    }
```

The program successfully adds alternate text "Figure without ALT" to all the images. However, the bytes of that figure is null.

Can you please tell what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What bytes do you expect to get? You are looking at the **StructTree** which only represents the structure of the document page.  The actual contents are elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I want to get hold of the image whose alt text is being added in the program. Can you please suggest how to proceed? I can write a separate program that extracts images but then I wont have access to alt of that image.